# HTTP 403 while pushing to hosted repo on phabricator

Tags: git, apache, phabricator

I'm running phabricator on a GCP instance (with ports 80/443 open). The apache2 process runs as www-data and is allowed `sudo` permissions.

```
www-data ALL=(root) SETENV: NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/git-http-backend
```

The phabricator daemons run as `root`. Right now, ssh cloning is not allowed and only http is allowed.

I've setup a user with VCS Password and while trying to push to a new repo (with `GIT_TRACE` and `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE` set), I get the following error:

```
* The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden
* Closing connection 2
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 403
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

In the apache's `other_vhosts_access.log`, I see the following line:

```
src.example.com:80 x.x.x.x - user [16/Feb/2016:05:03:32 +0000] "GET /diffusion/CS/repo.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 403 230 "-" "git/1.9.1"
```

Is there anything I am missing in my setup? What could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow changing my VCS password solved this. Closing the question.